# Craft console app within windows batch script

Tags: console

I try to create a simple deployment batch script that would work on windows.

To do that, I need to interact with Craft console app. How do I pass multiple commands to it to perform installation?

I tried this:

```
(echo mysql && echo localhost)|craft setup
```

This in theory should answer two first questions that craft console asks during installation. Unfortunetly it just caused console program to be stuck in some kind of loop when first question about the database is repeated infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows' `cmd`, commands are joined by two ampersands like you specified (`cd foo && dir`), however in PowerShell (which Microsoft is pushing to replace `cmd`), commands are joined by semicolons: `cd foo; dir`.

Also, it looks like you have an orphan closing parentheses `)` in your code. Is that supposed to be there?

Comment: Orphaned parentheses werejust mistake during pasting code here, just fixed. About powershell - i also tried to run script on it and i replaced `&&` with `;` but it didnt helped.